# Where did the google dictionary listen button go (on my Samsung Galaxy Phone)?

Tags: dictionary

I use a Samsung Galaxy E7 mobile phone with the latest Google Chrome web browser installed. My android operating system version also up to date. Since yesterday, I experienced that the 'listen' button (marked on the snap-shot) has gone from Google dictionary results. Here is a snapshot showing the missing icon which I captured from another mobile phone today.

[image]

Please suggest me a solution to get it back. It is really important to me as a student who learns English as the second language.

Comment: I don't have it either on my s5, but you can scroll down to the first website which should be Webster › dictionary in there the icon is available

Comment: The issue is it was there two days back. I do not understand the reason for the absence of the facility. It is still there when I load the same page from another mobile phone and from my laptop. Thanks for your comment

Comment: I would suggest you send feedback to Google chrome about the issue